# Having trouble splitting a specific string correctly

Tags: java, string, split

Hello this is my first time posting here, I did look around and I couldn't find an answer to the problem I'm having.

I need to turn this string into two strings:

```
"R(rndInt[-10,10]),R(rndInt[-10,10])"
```

to

```
 "R(rndInt[-10,10])" "R(rndInt[-10,10])"
```

To make a long story short, I am modding a game and creating my own scripting language for people to use. I made a class/method based structure (Notes on that here: http://pastie.org/8825346). Right now I'm trying to make it so that you can use Classes/Methods within methods(which works for single parameter methods).

The problem I'm having right now is splitting that string because it has multiple commas. I can't really think of a way to split it without causing problems.

Can anybody help? I am stumped right now.

**Edit: Solved!**

The lookahead assertion method works! I haven't heard of it till now.

I forgot to mention that I cannot use the "R". The R references a Class, which can have different names.

I came up with a solution for that issue by finding out what is between the ")," and "(" by sub-stringing the string.

```
String cName=oldStr.substring(oldStr.indexOf("),")+2);
cName=cName.substring(0, oldStr.indexOf("("));
System.out.println("CNAME:"+cName);
String[] test = oldStr.split(",(?="+cName+")");
```

Thank you guys, I am so grateful for the help :)

Comment: Please don't put [solved] or any of its variants in the titles of your questions.  The way you mark a question solved here is by clicking the checkmark next to the correct answer.

Comment: Please don't put tags in the title of your questions.  There is a tagging system already provided for this purpose.

Comment: Please don't put "Edit" or any of its variants like ETA in the body of your questions.  Every question has a detailed edit history that everyone can review; the edit history for your question can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/22136224/revisions

Comment: Finally, saying "thanks" in posts is nice, but unnecessary; the way we say thanks here is by upvoting answers that helped you.

Comment: Sorry about that, I'm new around here. Lesson learned.

Comment: That's all right.  Most people are used to how forums work; we bear very little resemblance to those.

Answer (score 1):

Why not targeting the concerned comma:

```
str.split("\\),R");   // as a simple Regexp
```

**UPDATE ----**

As pointing in comments and answered by @Reimeus, the regexp would end up to:

```
str.split(",(?=R)");
```

Comment: Your solution gotta make the splitted result being `R(rndInt[-10,10]` and `(rndInt[-10,10])`, which is not an optimal solution.

Comment: @AdrianShum Exact, thus go for the lookahead assertion :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

```
String[] array = str.split(",(?=R)");
```

Comment: Based upon the language spec the OP linked to, the second `R` character may sometimes be an `M`.  And may eventually be any classname, if I understand it correctly.

Comment: agreed, ultimately if OP wants robust solution JFlex/ANTLR would the way to go - this solution is only suitable a quick solution where a finite set of classes could be used

Answer (score 1):

If you're creating your own language, it's probably best to treat it as a language and do proper [lex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis)/[parse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parser#Parser).  There are some open-source tools available to assist with this, such as [JFlex](http://jflex.de/).

However, based upon your current language requirements, your structure is simple enough that you could get away with doing a `split()`, as suggested in the other answers.  That may or may not remain viable as your language evolves over time.

Answer (score 0):

There are numerous scripting languages out there, are you sure reinventing the wheel is the best use of your time? In case you are:

For non-trivial languages, parsing is typically done with a [parser generator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_parser_generators).

However, for simple cases, writing it by hand isn't too hard. A reasonable approach is [recursive decent parsing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser). In your case, this would look something like:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

abstract class Expression {

}

class MethodInvocation extends Expression {
    final String methodName;
    final List<Expression> arguments;

    MethodInvocation(String methodName, List<Expression> arguments) {
        this.methodName = methodName;
        this.arguments = arguments;
    }
}

class Literal extends Expression {
    final int value;

    Literal(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}


public class Parser {
    char[] input;

    /** index of next character to consume */
    int index;

    Parser(String input) {
        this.input = input.toCharArray();
        index = 0;
    }

    void consumeExpected(char ch) {
        if (input[index] != ch) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Syntax Error");
        }
        index++;
    }

    String identifier() {
        int start = index;
        while (index < input.length && Character.isAlphabetic(input[index])) {
            index++;
        }
        return new String(input, start, index - start);
    }

    Literal numericLiteral() {
        int start = index;
        if (input[index] == '-') {
            index++;
        }
        while (index < input.length && '0' <= input[index] && input[index] <= '9') {
            index++;
        }
        return new Literal(Integer.parseInt(new String(input, start, index - start)));
    }

    Expression expression() {
        if (Character.isAlphabetic(input[index])) {
            String methodName = identifier();
            consumeExpected('(');

            List<Expression> arguments = new ArrayList<>();
            if (input[index] != ')') {
                do {
                    arguments.add(expression());
                } while (input[index++] == ',');
                index--;
                consumeExpected(')');
            }
            return new MethodInvocation(methodName, arguments);
        } else {
            return numericLiteral();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Expression ex = new Parser("R(rndInt(-10,10)),R(rndInt(-10,10))").expression();
        System.out.println(ex);
    }
}
```